# Dovecot: SSL not working (no suitable signature algorithm), other daemons work just fine

Tags: ssl, dovecot, openssl

I try to secure my Dovecot with SSL/TLS using Letsencrypt certificates. Dovecot immediately closes any TLS connection and reports the confusing error "no suitable signature algorithm" in the logs.

I am using Dovecot 2.3.20 on Ubuntu 23.10. My OpenSSL version is 3.0.10. The Letsencrypt certificate works for fine for OpenLDAP (ldapd), Postfix and Apache. Clients are able to connect with TLSv1.3 using the cipher TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. The server TLS certificate has an EC key over P384r1.

Only Dovecot is not working. My Dovecot config

```
ssl = yes
verbose_ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/my-host.my-domain.tld/chain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/my-host.my-domain.tld/privkey.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = </usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
```

Whenever an connection attempt is made, Dovecot logs

```
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: where=0x4008, ret=552: fatal handshake failure
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: error
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A000076:SSL routines::no suitable signature algorithm
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A000076:SSL routines::no suitable signature algorithm (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=79.240.>
dovecot[345145]: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: SSL_accept() syscall failed: Invalid argument
```

On the client side, I tried to establish a connection via `openssl s_client -crlf -connect my-host.my-domain.tld:993` and recorded the packages with wireshark. There is a proper TLS hello from the client to the server (with a lots of suitable ciphers, signature schemes, etc.) and then a decoding error, because the server simply closes the connection.

Another interesting fact: If I try to limit the list of potential ciphers on the server side and set the Dovecot configuration to something like that

```
ssl_cipher_list = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Dovecot refuses to start altogether and claims that the ciphers are unknown.

Comment: *"Clients are able to connect with TLSv1.3 using the cipher TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384."* - this is impossible. This cipher is not available for TLS 1.3, only for TLS 1.2 and lower.

Comment: *"ssl_cipher_list = ..."* - these are all TLS 1.3 only cipher suites. There is currently no support to set these in a config (or maybe use `ssl_cipher_suites`?), i.e. `ssl_cipher_list` is only suitable for cipher suites defined with TLS 1.2 and lower. What was the original value of this option before you've tried to change it? Please provide `doveconf -a | grep ^ssl`.

Comment: Silly me, the entire problem was the path to the cert file. It must be `fullchain.pem`, not `chain.pem`. Only the former contains the client certificate, the latter only contains the CA certificates. All other daemons refer to `fullchain.pem`, too. I only noticed right now. It is working now.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich nit: in general TLS_kx_auth_WITH_symmetric suites can only be used with 1.2 and lower, but when the symmetric includes AEAD or SHA2 -- and this does both -- it can only be used with 1.2 _exactly_.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I'm as always impressed by the level of technical details you add. Thanks a lot.